# How to rewrite a text file in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

So if I have a code like this:

```
f = open('score.txt','r+')
playersScore = 1
oldscore = (f.read())
oldscore = int(oldscore)
score = oldscore + PlayersScore
f.write(str(score))
f.close()
```

The text file has 1 in it. If I try run the code it gives this error:

> oldscore = int(oldscore)
>   ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

How can I fix this? I'm a python beginner so please keep it simple.

Comment: Try `int(oldscore.strip())`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is caused by adding a new line instead of replacing the old line. This should work:

```
f = open('score.txt','r+')
playersScore = 1
oldscore = (f.read())
oldscore = int(oldscore)
score = oldscore + playersScore
f.seek(0)
f.write(str(score))
f.close()
```

Comment: That's a good idea. But it will slow things down, and for larger codebases, it could complicate things (Why open a file twice?). It does show good logic though, and the code itself is more verbose in a sense. :)

Comment: You could just seek back to 0 and write followed by a truncate. No need to reopen the file.

Answer (score 3):

You can see the values of what you are trying to do by printing them periodically.

```
f = open('score.txt','r+')
playersScore = 1
oldscore = (f.read())
print(oldscore) # Let's see what the value of this is!
oldscore = int(oldscore)
score = oldscore + playersScore
f.write(str(score))
f.close()
```

Even if the only contents of the file may look like something such as `3`, it may have a line break at the end (`\n`). You might want to get rid of that.

The `.strip()` method for strings is a good bet. It will get rid of line breaks at the beginning or end of the string.

This should be some working code:

```
f = open('score.txt','r+')
playersScore = 1
oldscore = (f.read())
print(oldscore) # Let's see what the value of this is!
oldscore = int(oldscore.strip()) # See how we called .strip()?
score = oldscore + playersScore
f.write(str(score))
f.close()
```

Comment: if the number in the text file is one it would make the number twelve.

Answer (score 2):

The above comment from Zizouz212 nailed it; your score.txt file contains additional characters, such as a newline, which cannot be converted to an integer. When populating the 1 in `score.txt`, you might have pressed the enter key before saving it.

Using `.strip()` on the value read from the line ensures that `int()` only receives the value from the line.

Also, your code sample capitalizes PlayersScore when adding it with oldscore. This is most likely a type-o in your post, but if not, this will also produce problems when running your program.

Comment: Your first paragraph is a little bit right, and wrong. I just tested that myself to verify it (it could be my text editor), but it seems that all files have a trailing newline which needs to be stripped. I wonder if it could have something to do with EOF markings...

Comment: I'm only able to produce the ValueError on the first run if I have a linefeed after the digit. I tried with CRLF and LF, but cannot further speculate.I agree that my first paragraph is prone to error, as the exact state of the OP's score.txt is unknown. 

My goal, much like I believe yours to be, is to encourage the OP to gain familiarity with non-printing characters in files, as that is where they are struggling. Moreso if the OP intends to run the program repeatedly, since the file is not parsed per line and cannot sustain repeated analysis of score.txt.

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
score = oldscore + PlayersScore
```

should be:

```
score = oldscore + playersScore
```

Try that.

Answer (score 0):

The error you got is because the file is empty or contains alpha characters (letters), I don't know why. Something else that's wrong, is that opening a file in mode `r+`, doesn't rewrite the file. You need to read the file, and then overwrite it.

```
f = open('score.txt', 'r')
playerScore = 1
oldScore = int(f.read())
f.close()
f = open('score.txt', 'w')
score = oldScore + playerScore
f.write(str(score))
f.close()
```

Answer (score -2):

```
playerscore = 1
for line in open('score.txt'):
    playerscore += int(line)
```

Comment: This doesn't match what the OP would like.

Comment: actually it does, the file only has 1 integer in it